# xpath usage in logi info

Tags: xpath

I have to massage some XML like this:

```
<Action ID="actDashboardRenamePanel" Type="Link"> 
<Target Type="Link" Link="javascript: LogiXML.Dashboard.pageDashboard.rdShowRenamePanel('rdDashboardPanelID', 'rdPnlInstanceID');" ID="tgtRenamepanel" /> 
</Action> 
</PopupOption> 
<PopupOption Caption="Remove" ID="ppoRemove_rdPnlInstanceID"> 
<Action ID="actDashboardRemovePanel" Type="Link" ConfirmMessage="Remove? Are you sure?"> 
<Target Type="Link" Link="javascript: LogiXML.Dashboard.pageDashboard.rdRemoveDashboardPanel('rdDashboardPanelID');" /> 
</Action> 
</PopupOption>
```

> 

within a Logi Analytics program.

I am using this XPATH:

```
<DefinitionModifier>
     <SetAttribute XPath="//Action[@ID[starts-with(.,'ppoRemove_')]]" Caption="Remove###" />
</DefinitionModifier>
```

Do I use starts-with correctly (it currently does not work).

Comment: Are you using `ID` of `<Action>` or `<PopupOption>`? The way i see you used `XPath="//Action[@ID[starts-with(.,'ppoRemove_')]]"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you meant to filter `<Action>` by `ID` of `<PopupOption>`. If this is the case, you can try following XPath :

```
//PopupOption[starts-with(@ID,'ppoRemove_')]/Action
```

Comment: Thanks. I just realised that the above XML was wrongly copied and pasted. I have edited it to reflect this. The solution is: <SetAttribute XPath="//PopupOption[starts-with(@ID,'ppoRemove_')]" Caption="Remove###" />. Thanks I will accept though.